# What exactly is getGlobalVisibleRect()?

Tags: java, android

Hi I been looking at the developer code for zoom a view and I can't seem to be figure out what this code suppose to do:

```
 final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(
        R.id.expanded_image);
expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);

// Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
// This step involves lots of math. Yay, math.
final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
final Point globalOffset = new Point();

// The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
// and the final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container
// view. Also set the container view's offset as the origin for the
// bounds, since that's the origin for the positioning animation
// properties (X, Y).
thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
findViewById(R.id.container)
        .getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
```

1) Specifically I am not so sure what `getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds,globalOffset)` suppose to do?

2) Also, what exactly does the `startBounds.offset()` suppose to do and what does `-globalOffset.x,-globalOffset.y` even mean?

Comment: Oh thanks. I found that linked before and It still didn't help so that is why I asked the question. Also I found two stackoverflow post trying to answer the question but the answer is very vague.

Comment: @HaniyehKhaksar that link is broken

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds,globalOffset) returns the container's view global position, and globalOffset is the offset of the whole screen. So in this code, globalOffset.x is 0, globalOffset.y is 75.(in my phone, the 75 is the status bar height) If I call finalBounds.off(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y), finalBounds has (0, 0 , origin-0, origin-75), meaning finalBounds is local coordinate not global.
   **Container view is important, because it supplies basis coordinate for two images.**
2. Before calling startBounds.offset, startBounds has global location of thumbView.
   startBounds.offset() does make startBounds to local coordinate of container view.
   finalBounds.offset() does the same thing. Now startBounds and finalBounds have same relative coordinate so that making transition animation is easy.
3. If use globalrect, width/height will be wrong.

Answer (score 21):

1. getGlobalVisibleRect(rect, offset) returns a boolean, stating whether the view is visible in the global coordinate.
2. getGlobalVisibleRect(rect, offset), the first rect is a output parameter that will be set to the visible rectangle of the view in global coordinate.
3. getGlobalVisibleRect(rect, offset), the second point is also an output parameter that is set to the coordinate of the left-top point of the View. Note as illustrated below, this offset can have negative values, meaning the left-top point of the view it's off the screen.

Reference: https://www.cnblogs.com/ai-developers/p/4413585.html

[image]

Comment: based on the illustration, why globalRect has negative value?

Comment: @Ian are you sure the values here are going negative?